# AS3 Instantiate a class with an optional Object

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I have a class that needs instantiating with an object:

```
public class FusePumpComboBox extends Sprite
{
    private var _rowCount;

    public function FusePumpComboBox(args:Object)
    {
        _rowCount = (args.rowCount !== undefined) ? args.rowCount : 5;
    }
}
```

What if I don't want to pass it a row count and instantaiate like this:

```
var obj:FusePumpComboBox = new FusePumpComboBox();
```

At the moment I get an error with mismatched number of arguments, as you'd expect. I've tried giving the `args:Object` a default value... I think this is where the solution lies, just don't know what to give it or how (`args:Object = {}`) doesn't work.

EDIT: I will also have getters and setters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
public function FusePumpComboBox(args:Object=null)
{
    _rowCount = (args && args.hasOwnProperty('rowCount')) ? args.rowCount : 5;
                       //      ^----- The correct way of checking the properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `null` as the default value and check if `args` is `null` within the method.

I must note that though this is common in JavaScript (parsing an object with settings), it's not a good practice to continue in the context of OOP.

Comment: Though please can you elaborate on your last edit? Where is the harm in giving properties values using the constructor?

Answer (score -1):

Answers above clarify the solution.

Just a side note: passing an argument to a constructor is a bad pattern.

It is better to maintain a property by getter and setter instead.

Parsing complex object args must be done outside as from what I understand it is not a class "own" functionality.

Comment: Really?? I would much rather have the size of the combo set during instantiation than have to redraw it after every 'set'. Surely that's less work? Please can you elaborate?

Comment: Doing something in constructor or right after object instantiation will happen in one frame during runtime. And actual drawing is better to postpone to the object validation. This is the way how Flex component framework organized. You can notice that Flex UI components never declare constructor arguments.

Comment: Flex components function in such a way, so that the properties could be marked up in MXML and to maintain integrity of both MXML and AS. There is more overhead in instantiating the object and then calling all the setters for it's properties, than just assigning all properties in the constructor. Postponing of drawing is irrelevant, because you can do it via Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE on both cases.

Comment: MXML is not the only reason. If you need to pass parameters, the preferred option is to have static creation methods. Especially because you can have many of them. Drawing in constructor or setters immediately will affect the performance. That is why invalidation technique is implemented in Flex framework.